Accessing Microsoft Project Online data via REST API
I have been using the Project Online API for years to extract data. Often using PowerBI (it works ok). Years ago I did it from an ETL that loaded the data into SQL Server and I also did it with Azure Data Factory (ADF1). Recently, I tried it with ADF2 and I couldn't (403 Forbidden). Since Microsoft Graph is now used, I preferred to do all the work, step by step, using Postman:

Register an App in Azure and give it delegated Sharepoint permissions (AllSites.Read Project.Read)
I got a (manual) code at
https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/v2.0/authorize
Once I received the code (from Postman), I used it to get a token, which I received successfully
I made a GET query
URL: https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{sitename}/_api/ProjectData/
Headers:
Authorization: Bearer {token}
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose

I get the same result as ADF2 (403 Forbidden).
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>20010, Microsoft.ProjectServer.PJClientCallableException</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="es-ES">GeneralSecurityAccessDenied</m:message>
</m:error>

The expected result is to receive the same thing that I receive when making the query from a browser authenticated with my user.
To verify, I have made a query to that endpoint, from a browser, authenticated with my user and I get data from the API. That is, the user has the appropriate permissions. I have also decoded the token with https://jwt.ms/ to verify that the permissions, the user, etc. are there (everything seems to be ok)
I have reviewed the information available on the Internet and I conclude two things:
A. There are many people having the same problem and no one has published a solution
B. Microsoft seems to be removing information about it. I am pretty sure that there was more and better information before
Is it possible that this possibility is being removed or is there a bug with the API?
Any suggestions?

Could you add API permissions Portal image by editing your question?
